# Displaying TinyMCE plugins the correct way

Tags: tinymce, joomla1.5

I have a problem with the tinyMCE editor thats included with Joomla! 1.5 . I want to have the editor displayed in Simple mode, but I want to include the hyperlink button and I do not want the Format and Styles dropdown list to be included, I tried to switch from Advanced and Extended and adjusted every option included but I just could not get it to display the hyperlink button without displaying the Format and the Styles dropdown menu? Is there anything I can do about this, maybe hacking and modifying the code etc? Any advise is accepted. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you think you all you need to do is to configure tinymce the right way - that is not the case.

You can use a slightly stripped down version of the advanced theme (maybe coming close to what you want); id do not know joomla that well, but it might be that you need to set the config variables in another way:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,link,unlink,bullist,blockquote,undo",
});
```

For sure you can code it yourself to make it work with the simple plugin (you would need to search through the core code in order to find the important parts in the code), but i would try to take the easier way.

Comment: Thx, Thariama, I took your advise and went through the core code and it worked ;-) I know it's not good to modify core code, but well I desperately needed that option. Thanks again

Comment: well, that was fast; please post your modifications here for others who are looking for a solution too (thx)

Comment: In the plugins/editors dir open tinymce.php file and +- line 528 place the normal tinyMCE.init code